# how to fetch a string from a string in JS/ReactJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I want to fetch a string from my website string.
suppose if I have a website `https://www.mrkashyap.com/users/manish` i want to fetch only the word `manish` or anything after users/
how can I?
I got the URL from `var str= window.location.href`
I am using this in ReactJS.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this if you know it will always be the same format:

`window.location.href.split('/')`

then it'll return an array and access the index in the array you want:

in this case `window.location.href.split('/')[4]`

Answer (score 0):

Get location.pathname:

```js
const url = new URL("https://www.mrkashyap.com/users/manish"); // url = location;
console.log(url.pathname.split("/").pop())
```